# intellij - cleanup code

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was wondering whether intellij has a feature that would allow it to scan through files and perform things such as organising imports, safely deleting unused functions and fields etc. This feature was very helpful in .NET in Resharper plugin. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Do you mean all at once, or one at a time (as in organise imports, then safely delete unused functions, etc.)

Comment: DOes it make a difference? I guess the underlying implementation will go one by one with all of them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a plugin for IDEA - FindBugs-IDEA. It scans for cases you listed and a lot more.

Comment: IDEA provides hundreds of code inspections out of the box. To address this question installing FindBugs is not needed, IDEA can already find and fix the problems outlined by @Bober02.

Comment: Yes, but FindBugs provides a way more inspections.

Comment: Are you sure about **a way more**? The list at http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html contains about **400** inspections, while IntelliJ IDEA has more than **600**: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/inspections.jsp.

Answer (score 12):

Use `Analyze` | **Inspect Code** with the corresponding options enabled to find unused code, in the results you can apply the fix to all the occurrences at once removing all the unused methods and fields.

Use `Code` | **Reformat Code** or **Optimize Imports** for the rest. Reformat Code has an option to optimize imports and you can run it on the whole project to do both operations globally in a single step.

It's also possible to optimize imports on the fly (enabled in Settings) and reformat/optimize imports when committing to the version control. Code inspections can be also executed before the commit to notify you about possible problems.

Comment: For lightweight, the analyze-inspect code.. is enough, instead of installing Findbugs/PMD/CheckStyle
For full inspection, it's better to use SonarQube standalone or running with Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

You can try it out using the trial.

As to the imports, yes, you can Organize Imports `ctrl-alt-o`, and you can choose to do so on the current file or on every file in the project.

Not sure if you can delete all unused methods in a project, but you do get warnings regarding methods/variables that aren't used and can be safely deleted (and IntelliJ does offer the option to safely delete).

Also, in the Preferences, you can setup a ton of things that you choose to be considered as warnings, depending on your coding style, conventions, etc.

Comment: In addition you could ask IDEA to optimize, reformat code on VCS commit

Comment: Yes indeed, when commiting IntelliJ at least checks for warnings and TODO's in your code, giving you the chance to verify them before you commit. That comes in pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use these 10 IDEA Inspections that maybe you're not using:

http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.com/2008/04/10-best-idea-inspections-youre-not.html

And from myself I like fighting with **NullPointerException** with help of **Intellij IDEA.**

Following inspections are helping me so much:

1. Constant conditions & exceptions
   [image]
2. @NotNull/@Nullable problems
   [image]